# Nested input with L4's validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Does anyone know how to validate nested input sets using the Laravel 4 validator?

I have a table with a set of line items, and each quantity field has the unique package id in square brackets in the name:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[package_one]" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[package_two]" />
```

This results in a nested input array:

```
<?php

array(
  'quantity' => array(
    'package_one' => 3,
    'package_two' => 12
  )
);
```

Which is exactly what i want, but i'm unsure how to specify rules for these items using the validator class:

```
// Does not work :-(
Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'quantity[package_one]' => 'numeric|required|min:1',
    'quantity[package_two]' => 'numeric|required|min:1'
));
```

This does not seem to work, neither does nesting the rules under `quantity`. Obviously there are workarounds to this like building a custom array of input yourself before passing it to the validator etc, but what i'd like to know is:

**is there a native, "Laravel" way of handling nested input like this?**

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way....

## Controller

```
$input = Input::all();
$input = array_merge($input, $input['quantity']);
Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
'package_one' => 'numeric|required|min:1',
'package_two' => 'numeric|required|min:1'
 ));
```

Validator does not look into nested arrays. just bring that array to the outer one and you are done. (you can unset `$input['quntity']` if you want after that)

loophole here is, it assumes that `$input['quantity']` is present in the array. You need to validate this before putting into validation.

Works but not efficient.

Answer (score -1):

You could make an extra Validator object just for the quantity input. It requires more code but i think it's more robust than merging in to one array